# php preg_match_all returns error message "preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'y' -- at line 5"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to do a simple `preg_match_all` but don't get it running.

Following the code:

```php
$regex= "get-/my/test/(?<{id1}>.*)/foo/(?<{f11}>.*)";
$template = "get-/my/test/hallo/foo/awwww123";


$match = preg_match_all("/".$regex."/",$template, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); 

var_dump($match);
var_dump($matches);
```

Executing the code I get the following error message:

```
E_WARNING : type 2 -- preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'y' -- at line 5
```

What I'm doing wrong?

My expectation is, that `$match` is `true` and `$matches` include the groups with names.

### Update

Ok, I added the `preg_quote` but why is the following code not matching?

```
$regex= "get-/my/test/(?<{if1}>.*)/foo/(?<{tf4}>.*)";
$template = "get-/my/test/hallo/foo/werner12";
$regex = preg_quote($regex, "/");


$match = preg_match_all("|".$regex."|",$template, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); 

var_dump($match);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: use `preg_quote($regex,'/')` before using the regex.

Comment: If you're using `|` as delimoiter, don't use `preg_quote`. What are you trying to match with `(?<{id1}>.*)`? Remove the curly baces.